# Error: Segment or tag targeting requires a valid App REST API key in onesignal

Tags: php, onesignal

JSON sent:

```
{
    "app_id": "245a10ea-8424-48b4-97f6-27c0f954b264",
    "included_segments": ["All"],
    "data": { "foo": "bar" },
    "contents": { "en": "English Message" }
}
```

JSON received:

```
{ "allresponses": "{\"errors\":[\"Segment or tag targeting requires a valid App REST API key.\"]}" }
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means pretty much what it says. You must include your OneSignal application's REST API Key as an HTTP header with your API request in order to send a notification to all of your subscribers.

You can review the examples in OneSigna's documentation [here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#create-notification) for guidance on how to do this.